# How to setup redirection from one site to another with changing endlink? WordPress

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am having an issue that is causing me a headache. We recently changed from an old website to a new one, and we are in the need of redirecting a lot of links. We might be talking thousands - it is items that customers can download. Let's say we have the websites: `www.oldsite.example` and `www.newsite.example`.

On the old site we have a lot of items that still needs to be accessible (it's just a download link, no access to the site). The download files are names something like `www.oldsite.example/12345`. They will always start with 1. On the new site, all download links will start with 2.

The issue I am facing is how to differentiate - and where to set up - a rule that says if the link the user is trying to access has something like `www.newsite.example/12223` (anything starting with 1), how do I then redirect to `www.oldsite.example/12223` - and make sure this does not happen if the link starts with 2.

We are using WordPress, and I am not entirely sure where you would put this rule? In `.htaccess`?
Anyways, I hope someone can shed some light on my problem, and nudge me in a general direction!

Comment: Since these requests will not need to go "through" your WP on the new domain, there should be no need to handles this inside of WP using add_rewrite_rule or anything like that, but should be possible directly via the .htaccess. `RewriteRule ^(1[0-9]+)$ http://www.oldsite.com/$1 [R=302]` should probably already do the trick, just make sure you put it _before_ WordPress' own rewrites.

Comment: If that works, you can change the status code from 302 to 301 (302 always preferable for testing, otherwise your browser cache might easily fool you after you tried to make any changes) - if you want those redirects to be permanent; if you were planning to move those downloads to the new site at some later point, sticking with 302 might make more sense.

Comment: @CBroe Shouldn't it be `[R=302,L]` or is that irrelevant with redirects?

Comment: @volkerschulz no, you're right, that should usually be added, otherwise it might continue rewriting the new URL if there are following rules that match.

Comment: Thanks for the help, cool to know! Where do you find information on what regex to use when doing redirects?